# add event on input angular 2 dynamic form

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamicform

I have a form create with dynamic form following the tutorial in the [cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) now I want catch when some input change so how can add `(change)` events, send the function to call as param; something like

```
  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'test',
    label: 'Test ',
    type: 'text',
    onChange: 'test()',
    order: 0
  })
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're creating this form dynamically, you should therefore have access to it in your controller. Angular 2 uses the concept of the ***[FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html)*** which is a very powerful tool for interacting with your form controls. I'll skip a lot of the details, but I'll point out a couple of things:

You've got access to FormControl.valueChanges, which might not be apparent from that doc because FormControl inherits from ***[AbstractControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html)***, a superclass that provides a huge chunk of useful functionality, much of which is very similar to the Angular 1 forms functionality.

Essentially, what you're looking to do is leverage *observables*. If you're unfamiliar with them, you should read about them. ***[Christoph Burgdorf has a great article on them](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html)*** and actually, conveniently for you, uses FormControl.valueChanges as part of his example on how to use them. Oh what a lovely day it is!

But basically, in a nutshell, you're looking to do something along these lines:

```
this.textboxControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
   //... do your stuff here with 'value'
});
```

This obviously assumes that you've got an instance of the form control that you're wanting to react to.

***IT IS EXTREMELY IMPORTANT*** that when using observables you *UNSUBSCRIBE* in the ngOnDestroy method in your controller; otherwise the subscription will hang around after you're done with it and you have a memory leak.